# How to detect if any 4G hardware modem installed on a computer in Ubuntu v14.04

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, modem, 4g

I got a new laptop from office Lenovo L460, it has micro sim slot on it but I have no idea whether it has hardware to support.

I can not open the back of the laptop to check this. Is there any software or command to check?

P.S.-Am not much familiar with ubuntu .

Thanks

Comment: Check the outputs of `lscpi` and `lsusb` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

See what `mmcli` gives you:

```
$ mmcli -L

Found 1 modems:
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/4 [Lenovo] H5321 gw
```

To get this command, install:

```
$ sudo apt install modemmanager
```

Comment: @ThomasWard people still land here when googling for this exact issue. 
And it that matters: Ubuntu 14.04 has the same `mmcli -L` command. Just checked with Docker.